# Can't kick out of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
#Fiery Elsa
#ID:899525
#Homework 2, Program 2


#Initialization
count=0
name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit:")

#Input
while name!=-999:
    count=count+1
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit:")
    shares=int(input("Enter number of shares:"))
    pp=float(input("Enter purchase price:"))
    sp=float(input("Enter selling price:"))
    commission=float(input("Enter commission:"))


#Calculations
amount_paid=shares*pp
commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
amount_sold=shares*sp
commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)

#Output
print("Stock Name:", name)
print("Amount paid for the stock:       $", format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
```

Program loops, but doesn't kick out to print output when you press -999. What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, the program should allow the user to input as many times as he/she wants until the user is done. For example: 3 sets of inputs resulting in 3 sets of outputs.

Comment: `name` is never an `int`, you need to check against the string `'-999'`

Comment: @AChampion I tried "quit" but that didn't work either

Comment: Can't replicate your error... changing to `'-999'` terminates the loop fine for me (as does `'quit'`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that `name` is type `string`, but you're comparing it to `-999` which has type `int`.

If you change your loop to read `name != "-999"` then the comparison works.  You'll need to refactor your code some more to make it behave the way you're wanting, but this should be a good start :)

Comment: I changed the comparison to reflect your recommendation but it still doesn't kick me out. It reads "-999" as company name still.

Comment: You could try comparing name.split(), in case you're getting a newline character as well as the input value?

Comment: -999 doesn't post output -- it takes another set of inputs and then posts output

Comment: your comment also flew over my head

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the value of name after each input.

```
stock_name = []   # make a list for stock name
shares = []   # change also all other input variables into list type

while True:   # this will allow you to loop the input part
    name = input()
    if name != '-999':  # this will evaluate the value of name
        stock_name.append(name)  # this will add your latest name input to the list
        # Do the same to your other inputs
    else:
        break  # exit your while loop

# you need another loop here to do calculations and output
# I think this is where your count variable should go to index your lists
```

Comment: Each time you input to your name variable it will overwrite the previous data. You need to change it into a list type.

Answer (score 0):

```
while name!="-999": #try this one
    count=count+1
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit:")
    shares=int(input("Enter number of shares:"))
    pp=float(input("Enter purchase price:"))
    sp=float(input("Enter selling price:"))
    commission=float(input("Enter commission:"))
```